# XQuery/XPath: How to get element with a lower element value compared to another element value

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xquery

I will give an example to better explain myself:

```
<company>
    <products>
        <product ean="111">
            <listingPrice>100</listingPrice>
        </product>
        <product ean="222">
            <listingPrice>500</listPrice>
        </product>
        <product ean="333">
            <listingPrice>1000</listingPrice>
        </product>
    </products>
    <shops>
       <shop id="1">
         <product>
           <ean>111</ean>
           <sellingPrice>90</sellingPrice>      
        </product>
       </shop>

       <shop id="2">
         <product>
           <ean>888</ean>
           <sellingPrice>10</sellingPrice>      
        </product>
         <product>
           <ean>222</ean>
           <sellingPrice>300</sellingPrice>     
        </product>
       </shop>

        <shop id="3">
         <product>
           <ean>222</ean>
           <sellingPrice>600</sellingPrice>     
        </product>
       </shop>


       <shop id="4">

         <product>
           <ean>111</ean>
           <sellingPrice>20</sellingPrice>      
        </product>

         <product>
           <ean>333</ean>
           <sellingPrice>140</sellingPrice>     
        </product>


       </shop>
   </shops>
</company>
```

I want to display all product with a selling price value with **at least 20% lower** than the listing price and it has to be the same product ean to compare the prices. At the end the shop id with its product ean, selling price and listing price gets displayed.

Example solution would be then:

```
<shop id="2">
     <product ean="222" sellingPrice="300" listingPrice="500"/>
  </shop>

  <shop id="4">
     <product ean="111" sellingPrice="20" listingPrice="100"/>
     <product ean="333" sellingPrice="140" listingPrice="1000"/>
  </shop>
```

What I got so far:

```
let $a := fn:doc('shop.xml'),
      $b := $a//products/* ,
      $c:= $a//shops/*
return 

for $x in $c
  let $z:=
 if ($x/product/ean = $b/@ean and $x/product/sellingPrice < $b/(listingPrice *0.8 ) )
 then 
 <shop id="{$x/@*}">
<product ean="{$x/product/ean}" sellingPrice="{$x/product/sellingPrice}" listingPrice="{$b/listingPrice}"/>
</shop>

return $z
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it helps factoring out references and comparisons to be reused in functions, also I like using the `!` map operator to keep expressions more compact:

```
declare variable $factor as xs:decimal external := 0.8;

declare function local:listing-price($product as element(product)) as xs:decimal?
{
    root($product)/company/products/product[@ean = $product/ean]/listingPrice
};

declare function local:check-price($product as element(product), $factor as xs:decimal) as xs:boolean
{
    $product/sellingPrice < local:listing-price($product) * $factor
};


/company/shops/shop[product[local:check-price(., $factor)]] 
!
<shop id="{@id}">{
    product[local:check-price(., $factor)] 
    ! 
    <product ean="{ean}" sellingPrice="{sellingPrice}" listingPrice="{local:listing-price(.)}" />
}</shop>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6y7

To load from a file you can prefix the path with a `doc()` call:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'xml';
declare option output:indent 'yes';

declare variable $factor as xs:decimal external := 0.8;

declare function local:listing-price($product as element(product)) as xs:decimal?
{
    root($product)/company/products/product[@ean = $product/ean]/listingPrice
};

declare function local:check-price($product as element(product), $factor as xs:decimal) as xs:boolean
{
    $product/sellingPrice < local:listing-price($product) * $factor
};


doc('https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/raw/master/xslt/2020/test2020051601.xml')/company/shops/shop[product[local:check-price(., $factor)]] 
!
<shop id="{@id}">{
    product[local:check-price(., $factor)] 
    ! 
    <product ean="{ean}" sellingPrice="{sellingPrice}" listingPrice="{local:listing-price(.)}" />
}</shop>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6y7/1 or with declare context item at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6y7/2.

Comment: How to I get access to the xml file when my file is local. Can I not use this statement ? -> let $a := fn:doc('shop.xml') to get access , because /company/..... won't work.

Comment: Instead of `/company/shops/shop[product[local:check-price(., $factor)]]` you would simply use `doc('shop.xml')/company/shops/shop[product[local:check-price(., $factor)]]`. Or use `declare context item := doc('shop.xml');`, then the path `/company/shops/shop[product[local:check-price(., $factor)]]` should work.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't give me any output. Why can you get access to $product/ean instead of  $product//shops/*/ean ? Also would be a solution with a for loop and if statements more difficult to do ?

Comment: Ok I get an output now but my shop id value is lost.

Comment: I can't guess how your sample code looks now exactly, raise a new question with the details show in formatted code samples and I am sure we can help fix that problem. With the `!` operator I have used the `<shop id="{@id}">` should suffice, if you have switched to `for` expressions you will need to use a variable reference in the attribute value template.

Comment: Ok thank you, the only thing I changed was that I added declare context item := doc('shop.xml'); Could you elaborate how the ! operator works because I think I didn't understand what that operator really does.

Comment: It is a mapping operator that applies the expression on the right hand side to each item in the sequence of the left hand side. So doing `exp1 ! exp2` is more compact and flexible than doing `for $item in exp1 return exp2WithVariableReferenceTo$item`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214002/discussion-between-lyaso-and-martin-honnen).